# How do I download a ZIP file with ngClick?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS function that I'm trying to make download a file by sending a GET request to `/download?id=10`.

```
$scope.download = function(){
  $http({
    url: "/download",
    method: "GET",
    params: {id:"10"} 
  });
}
```

This function is bound to a `button` tag: `<button ng-click="download()">DOWNLOAD</button>`.

When I click the button, nothing happens. But if I navigate my browser to `/download?id=10`, it downloads the zip file that was made in my backend.

How do I make the `ng-click` method download the file?

Comment: Give a try `<a href="/download?id=10" download>Download</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this

```
$scope.download = function(){

       window.loaction.href = "/download?id=10";

}
```

or

You can use

```
<a href="/download?id=10" download>Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `method:GET or POST` in  your function

```
  $scope.download = function(){
      $http({
        url: "/download",
        method:'GET'
        params: {id:"10"} 
      });
    }
```

For dynamic params:

```
 $scope.download = function(id){
  $http({
    url: "/download",
    method:'GET'
    params: {id:id} 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have a **`ng-click`** for a button, you can just replace with **`<a>`** element and add the **`href`** property,

```
<a href="/download?id=10" download>Download</a>
```

If you still want to have a button, use **`GET`** method to get the file,

```
$scope.download = function(){
      $http({
        url: "/download",
        method:'GET'
        params: {id:"10"} 
      });
    }
```